# I uninstall smashingmagazine_brand, but I still have this error when I tried to edit a product

Tags: magento-1.9, php, adminhtml

I have removed all files of smashingagazine_brand and also i deleted tables  'smashingmagazine_branddirectory_brand' and deleted following from core_resource table: 'smashingmagazine_branddirectory_setup' and 'smashingmagazine_brandexample_setup'

But still i'm getting error in admin when i go to

Catalog->Manage Products->and click on any products

Below i have given snapshot of error page
Sttil any tables is leftout then help me out[image: This is when i click on any products] [image: and this error page i'm getting]

Comment: Please contact the theme/extension developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the product attribute **brand_id** is not removed from the attribute table. Go to **Catalog -> Manage Attributes** and remove this attribute else if its already removed then clear the cache.

**Clear the cache**

Go to var/cache folder and remove all its contents. The easiest way is to run this command on shell. Make sure to change your directory to your document root

```
 rm -rf var/cache/*
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you installed that extension, a new *catalog-product-eav-attribute* `brand_id` has created by the installer script of that extension.

Now you  removed the code of this module and erased all assoicated tables. But you forgot to remove the attribute `brand_id` from the *eav-attribute-table* `eav_attribute`.

I think `brand_id` is of type *select-attribute*.So most probably it uses a *source-model* for this attribute which is normally used to specify the options and labels of that attribute. Since you have removed the code, the attribute can't find it's source model and hence you are getting this error.

So to avoid this, you need to completely remove the attribute `brand_id`. Use this :

```
DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = 'brand_id';
```

Comment: thank u , it worked

Comment: excellent observation. Kudos to Amit